# PySpark schema nullable not updated after filtering

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine I have a df with column which can be null, but if I apply operation to filter out nulls, shouldn't spark show dtype as not nullable ?

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a", 1), (None, 2)],
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("col_a", nullable=True, dataType=StringType()),
            StructField("col_b", nullable=False, dataType=IntegerType()),
        ]
    ),
)
```

```bash
> df.printSchema()
 root
  |-- col_a: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col_b: integer (nullable = false)
```

```bash
> df.filter(F.col("col_a").isNotNull()).printSchema()
 root
  |-- col_a: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col_b: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: filtering the frame (in your case removing the rows, but any type of filter you apply) will not change the underlying structure and its constraints.

Comment: Why not ? Usually for any kind of transformation datatype can change right ?

In reverse case if I am doing some transformation which may introduce nulls, spark will change type from nullable = false to nullable = true.

Comment: Having all non-null values doesn't mean it is nullable=False. it still has a possibility to be null.

Answer (score 0):

It Is not possible to change the Schema like that.

You should add a new column that is non nullable if you're really sure that you don't have null values

```
df.filter(F.col("col_a").isNotNull())
.withColumn("newColumn", coalesce(col("aNullableColumn"), col("col_a")))
//drop the original column if you want
```